# Issue with sonar java:S1948

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-plugin, sonarlint

I have a problem with understanding why I have an issue with SonarLint Intellij plugin:

```
public enum AuftragMessageStatus {
    SUCCESS, ERROR
}
```

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.io.Serializable;

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AuftragMessage implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2405172041950251808L;
    private AuftragMessageStatus status;
    private String text;
}
```

```
import lombok.Getter;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEvent;

@Getter
public class AdminAuftragEvent extends ApplicationEvent {

    private final AuftragMessage message;

    public AdminAuftragEvent(final Object source, final AuftragMessage message) {
        super(source);
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

I get critical java:S1948 issue: **Make "message" transient or serializable.**
What is wrong in my code? Or that is simple plugin bug?

Thanks in Advance, Wladi

Answer (score 1):

I think it was a bug in plugin. I pushed my changes to repository and remote sonar didn't find any Issue. Sorry for your time.